React Native Track Player-Error: Unable to parse @ReactMethod annotation from native module method: TrackPlayerModule.add().(kotlinx.coroutines.Job)
Problem Statement:
I am trying to develop a React Native app that can play music. I ejected the project from Expo and implemented React Native Track Player. However, when I try running the app on an Android device, the build is successful, but the app does not run and throws the following error:

Error: Exception in HostObject::get for prop 'TrackPlayerModule':
com.facebook.react.internal.turbomodule.core.TurboModuleInteropUtils$ParsingException:
Unable to parse @ReactMethod annotation from native module method: TrackPlayerModule.add().
Details: Unable to parse JNI signature. Detected unsupported return class: kotlinx.coroutines.Job

Environment Details:

React Native Version: 0.76.3
React Native Track Player Version: 4.1.1
Expo: Ejected to bare workflow

Steps Taken:

Installed React Native Track Player using npm install --save react-native-track-player.
Ejected from Expo to use the bare workflow.
Followed the installation instructions provided in the React Native
Track Player documentation.
Verified that the project builds successfully.
Encountered the above error when trying to run the app on an Android
device.

Expected Outcome: The app should run successfully on an Android device without throwing any errors.
Actual Outcome: The app crashes at runtime with the error mentioned above.
Question: How can I resolve this issue?
Any guidance or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

unfortunately React Native Track Player does not support new RN architecture at the moment.
so you have to either disable it

bare workflow: in file android/gradle.properties change newArchEnabled to false
expo: disabling it by setting newArchEnabled to false in your app.json

or try to apply suggested patch in this github issue.
also you can find more information about this problem in this PR from RN team, but RNTP team is still working on it.
hope it helps.

I am experiencing the same issue. I think it has to do with the package not being updated. I suggest you look for an alternative library or you downgrade your react native version.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

There’s no need to downgrade the react native version; the issue is that RNTP doesn’t support the new architecture yet. There are projects where ppl have gotten it to work but I believe the devs are waiting for the new architecture yet to be more stable

You can temporary solve it by changing file android/gradle.properties change newArchEnabled to false.As soon as react-native-track-player makes itself compatible with new react native architecture,you can turn it back to true.
